# WPF TextBox TextWrapping="NoWrap" doesn't work

Tags: wpf, textbox, word-wrap

I have a TextBox within a TabItem:

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
   <TextBox x:Name="FileContent" IsReadOnly="True"  
            Text="{Binding FileContent, Mode=OneWay}"
            TextWrapping="NoWrap"
            FontFamily="Courier New"
            />
</ScrollViewer>
```

Though TextWrapping="NoWrap", the long text lines still wrap. What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Apply wrapping to textblock inside txtbox :)

Comment: @retailcoder He is, isn't he? I just copy and pasted your example into vs and it is not wrapping for me.

Comment: It also worked as intended for me as well, is there more of the xaml that you can show us? Maybe a screen shot of the text wrapping will help identify where it's coming from.

Comment: Thanks. I guess it is not wrapping, but some hidden newline characters that cause the strange effect. And I cannot use TextBlock, as the text is actually multiline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, It was working in my test run. You have to do two different debugging to sort it out what was the issue exactly.

```
Debug 1:
```

Instead of binding just hard code the some bulk manually typed text at 'FileContent' `textbox`, then find out the result.

```
Debug 2:
```

Use binding once, then copy the 'FileContent' `textbox` binding result and hard code this value in that FileContent `textbox` again.

The excercise will keep you to find out the issue exactly. I hope this will sort it out your case.

Comment: Thanks, the text contained extra newlines.